# Can I slice one element in list?

Tags: python-3.x

I open a line from a text file and put it into the list. The problem is that the one element, that is in the list, has too many characters and I want to delete the unnecessary string

```
with open ("sesja1_1101_1.19o", "r", encoding = "UTF-8") as file:
    isIn = file.readlines()
    data = []
    for line in isIn:
        if "INTERVAL" in line:
            print(line)
            data.append(line)
```

I want to delete `INTERVAL` and unnecessary spaces with `/n`

```
result
data[0]
Out[45]: '     5.000                                                  INTERVAL            \n'
```

Comment: Why not just remove "INTERVAL" from the line? `line.replace('INTERVAL', '')` Edit: oh wait, you want to remove spaces too. In that case use regex: `re.sub(r'\s*INTERVAL\s*', '', line)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this link:[Python Remove Character from String](https://www.journaldev.com/23674/python-remove-character-from-string).
It will solve your problem.

```
with open ("sesja1_1101_1.19o", "r", encoding = "UTF-8") as file:
    isIn = file.readlines()
    data = []
    for line in isIn:
        if "INTERVAL" in line:
            line = line.replace('INTERVAL', '')
            print(line)
            data.append(line)
```